# Total variance on binomial statistic with uncertain probability

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, error-propagation

Consider an experiment to measure a random occurrence with a probability $p$ to pass some selection criteria. If I have $N$ independent trials and $p$ is known, this is a standard Binomial distribution $X=B(k;N,p)$ and the expected variance is $\sigma^2_X = Np(1-p)$.

Now if I don't know $p$ I might attempt to estimate it with a separate measurement or simulation.  If I have a single simulation with $n$ trials and $s$ successes, my best estimate for $p$ is $\hat{p}=s/n$.  Now I want to take the uncertainty in my knowledge of $p$ into account in my evaluation of the variance of $X$. To do that, I need to know the variance of $p$.

### Is the following chain of reasoning valid?

I know that my simulation should draw from a binomial distribution, which means I can say that

$\mathcal{L}(p) = B(s;n,p)$

I know that $p$ must be in [0,1], so I can normalize the likelihood as

$\mathcal{L}_n(p) = \frac{\mathcal{L}(p)}{\int_0^1\mathcal{L}(p)dp} = (n+1)B(s;n,p)$

Since $\mathcal{L}_n(p)$ is normalized, I can calculate

$E[p] = \int_0^1p(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp = \frac{s+1}{n+2} \quad \mathrm{and} \\
E[p^2] = \int_0^1p^2(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp = \frac{(s+2)(s+1)}{(n+3)(n+2)}$

and therefore

$\sigma_p^2 = E[p^2]-E[p]^2 = \frac{s+1}{n+2}(\frac{s+2}{n+3}-\frac{s+1}{n+2})$

To incorporate this into my estimate for $X$, I need to take the distribution of $p$ into account:

$X = \int_0^1 B(k;N,p)\mathcal{L}_n(p)dp = \int_0^1 B(k;N,p)(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp ;\\
E_X[k] = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^N kB(k;N,p)(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp \\
\phantom{E_X[k]} = \int_0^1 Np(n+1)B(s;n,p) dp \\
\phantom{E_X[k]} = N\frac{s+1}{n+2} \quad; \\
E_X[k^2] =  \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^N k^2 B(k;N,p)(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp \\
\phantom{E_X[k^2]} = \int_0^1 (Np+N^2p^2-Np^2)(n+1)B(s;n,p)dp \\
\phantom{E_X[k^2]} = N\frac{s+1}{n+2}\left(1 + \frac{s+2}{n+3}(N-1)  \right) \quad \therefore \\
\sigma_X^2 = E_X[k^2]-E_X[k]^2 = N\frac{s+1}{n+2}\left(1 + N(\frac{s+2}{n+3}-\frac{s+1}{n+2})-\frac{s+2}{n+3}\right)
$

If my number of simulation trials $n$ is large (say,O(1000) or so), then $n+3\sim n$ and $1/n\sim0$, which means the last experssion reduces to

$\sigma_X^2 \approx N\frac{s}{n}(1-\frac{s}{n}) = N\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$

### The impossible(?) conclusion

My uncertainty in predicting $X$ is the same whether or not I take into account my uncertainty in knowing $p$, so long as my number of trials $n$ for estimating $p$ are $\gg1$. How can this be true? In particular:

1. Nothing in this derivation relies on the relative size of $n$ to $N$.  But I would expect that if I estimate $p$ with a smaller sample size than my measurement that I would be introducing uncertainty.
2. Nothing in the derivation relies on the result $s$ of my trial.  But if this is a counting experiment, then $\sigma_s/s=1/\sqrt{s}$, so if $s$ is small, my uncertainty in $\hat p$ should be large.

### Did I go wrong somewhere, or is my intuition flawed?